# ElasticSearch ClassCastException - MappingMetadata to MappingMetadata

Tags: java, elasticsearch, classcastexception

I need your help. I haven't any idea whats wrong here.

When I start my JavaApp to get Data from ElasticSearch I get this ClassCastException:

```
ElasticDBPersistanceImp | findQueryField failed for templateId
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MappingMetadata cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MappingMetaData
    at com.initka.bprocess.hforms_formlist.persistance.impl.elastic.ElasticDBPersistanceImpl.getAllFields(ElasticDBPersistanceImpl.java:251) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.initka.bprocess.hforms_formlist.persistance.impl.elastic.ElasticDBPersistanceImpl.findQueryField(ElasticDBPersistanceImpl.java:226) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.initka.bprocess.hforms_formlist.persistance.impl.elastic.ElasticDBPersistanceImpl.getFieldDataDistict(ElasticDBPersistanceImpl.java:163) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.initka.bprocess.hforms_formlist.startup.FormListSecurityServiceImpl.getTemplateIds(FormListSecurityServiceImpl.java:40) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.initka.bprocess.hforms_formlist.startup.FormListSecurityServiceImpl.<init>(FormListSecurityServiceImpl.java:21) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.initka.bprocess.hforms_formlist.startup.HformsFormlistFactoryImpl.<init>(HformsFormlistFactoryImpl.java:55) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.initka.bprocess.hforms_formlist.startup.Booter.startTenant(Booter.java:70) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.initka.bprocess.hforms_formlist.startup.Booter.lambda$0(Booter.java:45) ~[classes/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
```

The code I'm using is provided at the Docs here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-get-mappings.html

So with a little bit of modification it looks like:

```
GetMappingsResponse mapping1 = dbManager.getFormlistDBConnection().indices().getMapping(getMappingsRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    Map<String, MappingMetaData> mappings2 = mapping1.mappings();
    MappingMetaData mappingMetaData = mappings2.get(indexName);
    Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = mappingMetaData.getSourceAsMap();
```

So maybe someone of you has an Idea whats wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching it seems that it was a chaching problem with maven.

After deleting my local maven repo an reload the sources it seems to work now.